# Kotlin - Getting resources works on macOS, but not Windows

Tags: java, kotlin, resources

I have this method to get an `ImageIcon` from a resource in the `src/main/resources` directory:

```kotlin
fun getIcon(name: String, width: Int, height: Int) : ImageIcon {
    val resource = {}.javaClass.classLoader.getResource("icons${File.separator}$name")
    val image = ImageIO.read(resource)
    val scaled = image.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)
    return ImageIcon(scaled)
}
```

And here's the `src/main/resources` directory:

[image: Resources directory]

This method works perfectly fine on macOS (both when running it directly from the IDE and when I run it as a JAR file), however the app crashes on Windows because `resource` is `null` when I try running the method like this:

```kotlin
clearNightIcon = getIcon("clearNight.png", 24, 24)
```

I'm using Gradle and IntelliJ IDEA if that matters.

Comment: `getResource` doesn't expect a file system file name. You're not getting files from the file system, you're getting classpath resources. It expects a classpath resource name. Just use `/`.

Comment: @Savior Oh wow, I spent at least an hour trying to figure this out and it was just as simple as that. Thank you! If you write an answer, I can mark it as solved.